# Resteasy: how to save JSON with not fixed keys

Tags: java, json, resteasy

I use reasteasy to call REST API.

My problem is that the JSON from the REST API has dynamic values. For example:

```
 "labels": {
           "kubernetes.io/hostname": "192.168.200.176",
           "node": "master"
         }
```

Where "node" and "kubernetes.io/hostname" could be any string.

I've tried to map "labels" into a `Map <String, String>` object. The variable is correctly created but it remains empty. How can I generate a dictionary with for example `{"kubernetes.io/hostname": "192.168.200.176", "node": "master"}`?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're fine with just creating a Map instead of a specific domain object, you can simply parse the JSON yourself to get a list of the keys and create the Map yourself.

Here's an example using [org.json](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.json%7Cjson%7C20160212%7Cbundle):

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.json.JSONObject;

public class Scratch {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String json = "{ \"labels\": { \"kubernetes.io/hostname\": \"192.168.200.176\", \"node\": \"master\" } }";
        Map<String, String> library = new HashMap<>();

        // parse the input string
        JSONObject labels = new JSONObject(json).getJSONObject("labels");

        // iterate over keys and insert into Map
        for (String key : labels.keySet()) {
            library.put(key, labels.getString(key));
        }

        System.out.println(library);
        // {kubernetes.io/hostname=192.168.200.176, node=master}
    }
}
```

You can also do more-or-less the same thing with [Gson](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.google.code.gson%7Cgson%7C2.7%7Cjar), by simply wrapping the Map in a container class, and letting it do the actual deserialization:

```
import java.util.Map;
import com.google.gson.Gson;

public class Scratch {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String json = "{ \"labels\": { \"kubernetes.io/hostname\": \"192.168.200.176\", \"node\": \"master\" } }";

        Library library = new Gson().fromJson(json, Library.class);
        System.out.println(library.labels);
        // {kubernetes.io/hostname=192.168.200.176, node=master}
    }
}

class Library {
    Map<String, String> labels;
}
```

In both cases, notice that you have to get the data from inside the "labels" field of the JSON, not the top level.